# Get column to fill 100% of remaining space in position absolute tbody

Tags: html, css

A simple quick question, i have this HTML

```
<div id="list">
    <table class="t">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="w100"><div>ID</div></th>
          <th><div>NAME</div></th>
          <th class="w100"><div>EXTRA</div></th>
          <th class="w100"><div>EXTRA1</div></th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
            <tbody style="top: 0px;" page="0">
              <tr>
                 <td class="w100">ID</td>
                 <td>NAME</td>
                 <td class="wr100">EXTRA</td>
                 <td class="w100">EXTRA1</td>
              </tr>
          <tr>
                 <td class="w100">ID</td>
                 <td>NAME</td>
                 <td class="wr100">EXTRA</td>
                 <td class="w100">EXTRA1</td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#list {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.t {
    height: 20000px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.t>tbody {
    position: absolute;
    border:solid 1px;
}
tr {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
.w100 {
    width: 100px;
}
```

how can I extend the NAME column to fill up the remaining space inside a position `absolute` tbody just like the thead does?

I need this css to remain like this:

```
.t>tbody {
    position: absolute;
}
```

and the table must have a height so that I can scroll past the tbody content

everything else can be changed

here is a demo

```
https://jsfiddle.net/wyzixg/f3gqgjgj/5/
```

Can this be achieved by css and/or js/jquery?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's great that you provided a fiddle (that will really help us to play with the code and change it to make it work)... but fiddles, by their nature, fiddles are temporary, and we want stack overflow to be forever... each question must stand alone and contain everything necessary to solve the problem. So... could you please: 1) copy out the parts from the fiddle that are relevant to this question (you don't need all of it). 2) explain in words: what you expect the end result to look like, and what you are seeing instead.

Comment: I updated my answer to take into account the absolute position on `tbody` that you need, please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the following is what you need.

You were pretty close, except that the absolute positioning was confusing the auto sizing algorithm used in table layouts.

If you set the width of the table to 100%, then the table will resize the columns to fill up the space.  Since you set the width of all columns (except the 2nd one for NAME) to 100px, any remaining width will be allocated to the 2nd column since its width will be `auto`.

Since you need the `tbody` element to be `position: absolute`, you can still get the auto table sizing effect by using `display: table` on `tbody`, which looks a bit bizarre but it might do the trick.

I am not sure if your JavaScript will work as expected, but the layout seems to be what you need.

There is an artifact, a second horizontal scroll bar, which can probably be removed with some experimentation, but I did not try it (yet).

```css
body { margin: 0;}
.c-list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 99%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
table {
}
.t tbody {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
table td {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.w100, .wr100 {
  width: 100px;
}
.wr100 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-list">
  <table class="t">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="w100">ID</td>
        <td>NAME</td>
        <td class="wr100">EXTRA</td>
        <td class="w100">EXTRA1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w100">1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="wr100">1</td>
        <td class="w100">1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w100">2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="wr100">2</td>
        <td class="w100">2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w100">3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="wr100">3</td>
        <td class="w100">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w100">4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="wr100">4</td>
        <td class="w100">4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w100">5</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class="wr100">5</td>
        <td class="w100">5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, but as i said i need the .c-list and .t > tbody to be absolute, that's the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `<thead>` for table headers, along with `<th>`, so you can set the header width to 100% to fill the remaining space, and it will apply for the entire column.

Check this snippet for a better view of the result.

Also you don't really need the height for the table, and `absolute`.

```css
.c-list {
  position: absolute;
 width:99%;
 height:400px;
 overflow: auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
table td {
 text-align: center;
 border:solid 1px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.t > tbody {
position: absolute;
width: 99%;
}
table {
 width:100%;
}
table tr{
 width:100%;
}
table tbody {
 width:100%;
}
.w100 {
 width:100px;
}
.wr100 {
 width:100px;
 text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-list" >
  <table style="height: 2000px;" class="t">
    <tbody style="top: 0px;" page="0">
      <tr><td class="w100">ID</td><td>NAME</td><td class="wr100">EXTRA</td><td class="w100">EXTRA1</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="w100">1</td><td>1</td><td class="wr100">1</td><td class="w100">1</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="w100">2</td><td>2</td><td class="wr100">2</td><td class="w100">2</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="w100">3</td><td>3</td><td class="wr100">3</td><td class="w100">3</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="w100">4</td><td>4</td><td class="wr100">4</td><td class="w100">4</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="w100">5</td><td>5</td><td class="wr100">5</td><td class="w100">5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried with the thead and th, but since tbody needs to be position: absolute; it only makes the thead row behave like i want, as i said i need .c-list and .t > tbody  to be absolute ... i think some js will do it but what i have tried so far is not working, i tried to measure the c-list div and calculate the remaining free space but there are different scroll sizes and it get's off by a few px.. I'll keep trying

Comment: Why only the Tbody must be absolute? The entire table being absolute will work the same way.

Comment: i am adding different tbodys inside the main table on demand at specific heights, a smarter pagination, main table has a specific height let's say 20000px and i know i have to display 1000 records each 20px height, and first i only display the first tbody that i know it has 100 rows that is 2000px, and when the scroll hits 1500+ pixels i append the next tbody that has a top : 2000px; and so on, everything works except this column fill.. so the main table needs to be absolute inside the div so i can specify the view port and the tbody must be absolute so i can add it to specific height..